# Calling function with varying number of parameters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parameter-passing, cell-array

I am using symbolic toolbox to generate a matlab function. But the number of input to the generated function is varying with the number of objects that I need (e.g., number of switches). For 2 and 3 switches the generated function look likes this :

```
y = fun(a1,a2,b1,b2)
y = fun(a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3)
```

In the script using this function I establish vectors of these parameters:

```
a = [a1 a2 ...]
```

What I want is to either call the generated function directly or make a wrapper function, so that I do not need to change the call statement when I change the number of switches. To complicate this problem even more, these variables are ACADO variables. That means that matrix and element-wise operation is not allowed (i.e., all math operation must be done with scalars, and equations in symbolic toolbox must be written for scalars).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably look for cell arrays and the `{:}` operator. It changes the contents of the cell to a [coma separated list](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). The result can be passed to a function as parameters. For example:

```
v2 = {a1, a2, b1, b2};
v3 = {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3};
```

And an example function:

```
function fun(varargin)
    display(['number of parameters: ' num2str(nargin)]);
```

You can call the function for different number of parameters 'transparently' as follows

```
fun(v2{:})
number of parameters: 4

fun(v3{:})
number of parameters: 6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create functions with variable numbers of input arguments with [`varargin`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html).

```
function fun(varargin)
a = cell2mat(varargin); % works only if arguments indeed only consists of scalars.

% your code comes hereafter
```

Comment: I do not think that solves my question, because I can not make the function with varying number of parameters, since it is generated by symbolic toolbox (http://www.mathworks.se/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html)

I tried to use vargin but I can't make it work:

    f = @(x,y) (x+y);
    vargin{1} = 1;
    vargin{2} = 2;
    f(vargin)

Comment: The answer provided by @angainor is probably the way you should go.