# Want to use a vector as parameter to a function, without having to separate its elements

Tags: function, matlab, parameter-passing

If I call a matlab function with:
 ***func(1,2,3,4,5)***
it works perfectly.

But if I do:
 ***a=[1,2,3,4,5]***  %(a[1;2;3;4;5] gives same result)

then:

***func(a)***

gives me:

*??? Error ==> func at 11
 Not enough input arguments.*

Line 11 in func.m is:

***error(nargchk(5, 6, nargin));***

I notice that this works perfectly:

***func(a(1),a(2),a(3),a(4),a(5))***

How can I use the vector 'a' as a parameter to a function? I have another function otherfunc(b) which returns a, and would like to use its output as a paramater like this ***func(otherfunc(b))***.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling function with varying number of parameters in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741843/calling-function-with-varying-number-of-parameters-in-matlab)

Answer (score 6):

[Comma-seperated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?refresh=true) 
(CSL) can be passed to functions as parameter list,

so what you need is a CSL as `1,2,3,4,5` constructed from an array.

It can be generated using cell array like this:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5];
c = num2cell(a);
func(c{:});
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could try with nargin - a variable in a function that has the value of the number of input arguments. Since you have a need for different length input, I believe this can best be handled with varargin, which can be set as the last input variable and will then group together all the extra input arguments..

```
function result = func(varargin)
    if nargin == 5: % this is every element separately
        x1 = varargin{1}
        x2 = varargin{2}
        x3 = varargin{3}
        x4 = varargin{4}
        x5 = varargin{5}
    else if nargin == 1: % and one vectorized input
        [x1 x2 x3 x4 x5] = varargin{1}
```

I've written `x1...x5` for your input variables

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to create a separate inline function. Say you have a function f which takes multiple parameters:

```
f = f(x1,x2,x3)
```

You can call this with an array of parameter values by defining a separate function g:

```
g = @(x) f(x(1),x(2),x(3))
```

Now, if you have a vector of parameters values v = [1,2,3], you will be able to call f(v(1),v(2),v(3)) using g(v).

Answer (score 0):

Just make the function take a single argument.

```
function result = func(a)
    if ~isvector(a)
        error('Input must be a vector')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since arguments to functions in Matlab can themselves be vectoes (or even matrices) you cannot replace several arguments with a single vector.
If `func` expects 5 arguments, you cannot pass a single vector and expect matlab to understand that all five arguments are elements in the vector. How can Matlab tell the difference between this case and a case where the first argument is a 5-vector?

So, I would suggest this solution

```
s.type = '()';
s.subs = {1:5};
func( subsref( num2cell( otherfunc(b) ), s ) )
```

I'm not sure if this works (I don't have matlab here), but the rationale is to convert the 5-vector `a` (the output of `otherfunc(b)`) into a cell array and then expand it as 5 different arguments to `func`.
Please not the difference between `a{:}` and `a(:)` in this `subsref`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function of the following form:

```
function [ out ] = funeval( f, x )
   string = 'f(';
   for I = 1:length(x)
      string = strcat( string, 'x(' , num2str(I), '),' );
   end
   string( end ) = ')';
   out = eval( string );
end
```

In which case, `funeval( func, a )` gives the required output.

Answer (score 0):

Use eval:

```
astr = [];
for i=1:length(a)
    astr     = [astr,'a(',num2str(i),'),']; % a(1),a(2),...
end
astr  = astr(1:end-1);
eval(['func(' astr ');']);
```