# Modifying field values of structure! <Matlab>

Tags: matlab

I have .mat file format that I want to modify to pass to another software.
the file has 1x1 struct (name:data) with 4 fields. one of them is a 1x15 struct (name: event) with another 4 fields. I want to modify these fields. 
For example, the first one is 'time' which I tried to modify in different ways:

```
data.event.time=[1:15];
```

and I get the error:

```
"Scalar structure required for this assignment"
```

Also tried:

```
data.event = setfield(data.event,'time',1:15);
```

and got:

```
 "Scalar structure required for this assignment.

Error in setfield (line 33)
    s.(deblank(strField)) = varargin{end};"
```

I know that I don't understand the mechanism of structures on Matlab so my question might be kinda stupid but it is my second time to use it.

Comment: What is that structure? there is missing information here. If you do `a.b.c=[1:15]` it works perfectly, so it is something about that structure that is blocking you from doing that.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with "what is that structure". I mean what could be the missing information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:

```
for t=1:15
    data.event(t).time=t;
end
```

If you have a vector that you want to assign to multiple elements of a struct, a loop is the easiest way.

Unfortunately there does not appear to be a nice way to directly assign elements of a vector to elements of a struct.

It's probably possible without a loop if you change your vector to a cellarray, but I personally find that counterintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested by Dennis Jaheruddin, you can avoid a for loop by converting to a cell array and using the builtin [`deal`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) function as follows:

```
timeCell = num2cell(1:15);
[event.time] = deal(timeCell{:});
```

You [need to convert to a cell array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15075444/7621674), because you want to use the different vector elements as arguments for the `deal` function.

Comment: This worked for a cell array of strings: `timeCell = {'A1', 'A2', 'A3'}`

Comment: Actually, `deal` worked directly, with no need for a cell array first.  `[event.time] = deal('A1', 'A2',  'A3')`