# Replacing multiple values in a structure

Tags: matlab, structure

I have a structure with `sample` being a numeric vector. I would like to replace the numbers in `sample` by `sample/2`. However, I do not know how to overcome the following error:

> Scalar structure required for this assignment.

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Example:

```
field1 = 'event';
value1 = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
field2 = 'sample';
value2 = 22;

A = struct(field1, value1, field2, value2);
```

What I want to do:

```
A.sample = round([A.sample]/2,0);
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example or an example of `A.event.sample`

Comment: What does `size(A.event)` return?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying field values of structure! <Matlab>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768606/modifying-field-values-of-structure-matlab)

Comment: Your code creates `A.event` and `A.sample`, not `A.event.sample`

Comment: Note that I changed `A.event.sample` to `A.sample`, because error message is not related to `A.event.sample` mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`deal`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) function to distribute your calculated matrix to the elements of your structure:

```
sampleCell = num2cell(round([A.sample]/2,0)); % first convert result to cell, to comply with the `deal` syntax
[A.sample] = deal(sampleCell{:});
```