# Functions defined by "inline" with vector input in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Defining a function with

```
f = inline('x+P1*P2-P3',3);
```

one can calculate `f(1,2,3,4)`, `f(0,1,2,1)`, etc.

How should I write the function `f` so that I can use vectors such as `1:4` or `[2,3,6,4]` as an input?

Comment: Do you mean `f = inline('x+P1*P2-P3',3);`? What behavior do you expect? What happens now if you try `f(1:4,2,3,4)`? Also, you should be using [Anonymous Functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) instead of `inline` which is deprecated.

Comment: @jodag: Thanks for that!  I put a 4 there to make sure the code works. 3 should work as well. I was trying to fix some old implementation of [numerical algorithms](https://sites.google.com/site/numericalanalysis1burden/module-7/matlab), which used that function.

Comment: @jodag: you are right. One should have `3` instead of `4` there if `f` has only 4 arguments. Fixed. (I didn't notice this problem until I tried to find my own answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The posted code works because of the extremely rigid structure allowed by the deprecated [`inline`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inline.html):

> `inline(expr,n)` where `n` is a scalar, constructs an inline function whose input arguments are `x`, `P1`, `P2`, ... .

Note: "`inline` will be removed in a future release. Use [Anonymous Functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) instead."

Noting the note, you can duplicate the behavior of the posted code by doing:

```
f = @(x,P1,P2,P3) x+P1*P2-P3;
```

You can also get your desired behavior by just having an `x` and indexing it within the body of the anonymous function:

```
f = @(x) x(1)+x(2)*x(3)-x(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just learned from these two answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30075471/758077
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12742906/758077

that the keyword is [Comma-Separated Lists](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?refresh=true). One can simply use

```
f = inline('x+P1*P2-P3',3);
a = [1,2,3,4]; % or a = 1:4;
c = num2cell(a); 
f(c{:})
```